# If we put an metal electrode in water with no metal ions present potential should tend to minus infinity?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

If we consider an equilibrium between metal electrode and its ions in solution we know that equilibrium potential is proportional to activity of ions in solution from Nernst equation. Since this dependence is logarithmic, what we conclude is that when activity of ions tends towards zero, potential tends to minus infinity. If we do place a metal electrode in pure water, would its potential decrease continously if we disregard any kind of other processes on it like corrosion which create their own potential?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The potential is in principle infinite if the water is pure. But in reality, when a metallic plate is dipped into pure water, you cannot prevent one or two atoms from being oxidized by air and pass into solution. On the other hand, the same thing can be said about $\ce{O2}$ producing one or two $\ce{OH-}$ ions. As a consequence the potential goes quickly from infinite to a finite value.

Comment: Very good answer- this used to puzzle me when I was a student too that the Nernst equation must go to infinity but of course when I started teaching I had to look for an answer lest a student ever ask it.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a model issue? Most equations in science have regimes of applicability and it is invalid to extrapolate outside those regimes. My opinion is that the Nernst equation simply does not apply for pure water with an inert metal electrode, e.g., platinum, inserted in it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, in reality corrosion processes(reduction of oxygen) would determine the potential.

Comment: Regarding other comments, Nernst equation is derived from second law of thermodynamics and as such it must hold for any activity of metal ions since this law doesn't put any constraints in terms of activity.

Comment: I will wait until the derivation and assumptions are explicitly given. I wonder what Nernst actually did.

Comment: Nernst law has no limit at very low concentrations. It may even be applied when there is less than 1 ion in one liter solution. This is the case when determining the solubility product of substances like $\ce{HgS}$ which is $\pu{1.4 10^{-53} mol^2 L^{-2}}$

Comment: Frankly, I doubt this. The second law of thermodynamics is ultimately based on quantum mechanics and classical laws are classical limits of quantum mechanics principles and derivations. So I doubt the Nernst equation, though extremely useful in typical situations, is strictly valid down at the bottom. I would be delighted to be proven wrong, but, until then, I see no compelling reason to believe the Nernst equation is not a classical limiting case. I will say nothing more and not vote up or down.

Comment: @Ed V Frankly I also doubt it. I cannot imagine of a chemical reaction happening on an electrode with an ion that is practically absent in solution. Less than $1$ ion par cubic kilometer seems absurd. But the potential of this Mercury electrode on a $\ce{Hg/HgS}$ can be measured and it is so different from the standard redox potential that the difference, divided by $\pu{ 0.0296 V}$, it yields a logarithm equal to $53$. As a consequence the mercury concentration is $\pu{10^{-53} M}$ .

Comment: I looked at the wikipedia article on the Nernst equation and the short section on limitations notes that the assumption of thermodynamic equilibrium is an issue down at the bottom. I am not trying to give you any grief, it is just my normal skepticism: down in the single digits of the ultra-small, issues of quantum statistics matter. Anyway, this was a thought-provoking question and answer and I am glad the Nernst equation is so reliably robust.

Comment: I think the answer to the OP’s question is no. Consider [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/62665/79678) by Ben Norris and assume his posited concentration cell and concentrations. Then, if the two solutions are each 1 L, there is very low probability, via the Poisson distribution with the low concentration as the mean value, of having any mercuric ions in the solution on the low concentration side of the cell. Solution volume can be increased, to have a reasonable probability of having several mercuric ions present, but then they will not just be staying near the electrode.

Comment: So then you have concentration shot noise: the cell cannot sense the concentration except in the vicinity of the electrode and, on average, almost nothing but water is there. Increasing the electrode area increases the parasitic stuff, e.g., electrode capacitance, etc. So there is a quantum limit to the concentration cell and its ability to perform at extremely low concentrations.

Comment: Well, yes. Wikipedia helped here as you said. In practice, we would never reach potentials predicted by Nernst since kinetics now becomes an issue because at such low activities exchange current density is also very low. Thermodynamics and kinetics are two distinct areas. It is like with diamond/graphite transition, even though thermodynamics says that diamomd should change to graphite, we never see it in real life since kinetics is extremely low in that case. Other reason is that in reality other processes which happen tend to define its potential rather than metal/ion equilibrium.